# Personal AES keys storage idea not working reason

Tags: security

I went through different ideas about storing AES key for encrypting database columns, I learnt that there are the possible solutions:

1. put the key in the database
2. find a Key Management Service to help you keep the key

Below is my suggestion:

3. prompt the user to input the key everytime he/she uses the database, it is a sentence he/she sets. After removing non-numeric characters, it has 256 bits for AES-256 to use.

So why (3) does not work, coz if not a lot of people is using now?

And why (1) works if someone accesses the database, and simply gets the key and decrypts the columns?

Why (2) works if someone gets your Key Management Service credentials in your source code?

What is the most secure way that is available to keep the AES key?

Comment: Instead of removing non-numeric characters you should hash what the user types in, with SHA256, or better, scrypt.

Comment: What is the purpose of this database? What does it do?

Comment: If you hash the things, you cannot recover. The database stores stuff that needs to be recovered, such as where a person lives at.

Comment: Hash the password, not the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have suggested is probably the most secure of the three options<sup>1</sup>, and is pretty much what an offline password manager like [KeePass](https://keepass.info/)<sup>2</sup> does.

However, it is also the least convenient. Security is always a trade-off between protecting the data and convenience, and having to enter my deliberately complicated passphrase every single time I want to get access to the data in the protected store means that I put only the most sensitive data in that store. Less sensitive data gets stored in other places.

<sup>1. Although "removing non-numeric characters" is a terrible, terrible idea. **Never roll your own cryptography**.

2. No affilitation.</sup>

Comment: You mean I shouldnt help the user to define the key? If someone sets "1234567890.abcdefgh" as the key, I use JavaScript or something else to remove the . away. Next time the user logins and type the . again, and I remove it. Bingo! His/Her key should be the same one - "1234567890abcdefgh"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function **Never roll your own cryptography**

Answer (score 1):

In most systems the database is abstracted from the user behind some sort of service, and that service may need to access user data when the user is not present. This may be to allow other authorized users to access the data, offline reporting purposes, or batch compute systems. If the data needs to be accessed when the user is present, this requires that the key is stored in the system and not provided by the user, as otherwise the system would not be able to decrypt the data for these cases as it would not have access to the key.

If the data does not need to be accessed separately from the user, rather than waiting to hit the database with a key that has traveled from the point of access, it is more secure to encrypt at the client and have the database only handle opaque blobs. This is usually sufficient in most cases where user specific keys would be possible.